# JS/jQuery modifies the CSS property set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, merge

Running the following jQuery bit changes the actual CSS properties applied to the DOM element. Why is this so?

```
jQuery("<div></div>")
  .css("background-image", "url(http://a.com/a.jpg)")
  .css("background-size", "cover")
  .css("background-position", "center center")
  .css("background-repeat", "no-repeat")
  .attr("style")
```

The above produces the output (`center` has been changed to `50%`):

```
background-image: url("http://a.com/a.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

I tried to do the same thing using plain JS, and it still modifies the value:

```
document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundPosition = "center center"
```

Why does this happen? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: `50%` and `center` are actually the same values for `background-position`. see: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/

Comment: Words like "center" "left" etc are just shorthand notations for convenience, how each HTML rendering engine should interpret them is a whole different story.

Comment: @Satpal I expect "center" and not 50%

Comment: @InsOp I don't mind how the engine interprets it, what I want is my values to be attached to the DOM as I supply them. The biggest issue is that sometimes it gets really bad and converts all four properties into one "background" property, which might not be supported on lower Android devices